# Android Volley Dependency

Tags: java, android, android-volley

The dependency for Volley appears to run in to a compile error and I am not sure why? Here is my dependency code and the error message produced.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
}
```

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>

```
 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         AndroidHive:app:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mcxiaoke/volley/library-aar/1.0.0/library-aar-1.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mcxiaoke/volley/library-aar/1.0.0/library-aar-1.0.0.pom'.
               > peer not authenticated
```

After trying the newer version of Volley I now recieve this compile error:

```
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.7
```

Complete build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.george.androidhive"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

Comment: Does it give error when you Sync Gradle?

Comment: @Sharj Yes, I will try again to make sure.

Comment: check https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley for latest version : `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'` use this.

Comment: Still recieve a 'cannot resolve' error message when running a rebuild

Comment: First clean your project and close Android Studio and then try again.

Comment: Done that now, still says cannot resolve?

Comment: post your complete build file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

**Updated**:

This project has been deprecated. Use the official version from jCenter

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

Comment: not working for me, is there any requirement on gradle version / api version?

Comment: @artdias90 it should work. Now you can also directly use the official version. see the updated answer.

Comment: I am unable to use the updated dependency, neither am I able to find it in the dependencies list for libraries. Is there something else I need to do? I was using compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19' till date.